How can I correctly decrypt AES 256 CBC in c?
I am trying to decrypt some of a zlib compressed file. I can decrypt it online using CyberChef. I am trying to write a c program to do the same thing.
The following is the simplified program.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <zlib.h>


void print_hex(unsigned char *bytes, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%02x", bytes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void hex_to_bytes(const char *hex, unsigned char *bytes, size_t bytes_len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes_len; i++) {
        sscanf(hex + 2 * i, "%2hhx", &bytes[i]);
    }
}

void handleErrors(const char *error) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    printf("Error: %s\n", error);
    abort();
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors("Cipher");
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv)) handleErrors("Init");

    if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len)) handleErrors("Update");
    plaintext_len = len;

    if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors("Final");
    plaintext_len += len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *hex_key = "5d2d59930aefae47621f5150f42bf746";
    const char *iv_hex = "e832316700da4d9bbb316f961b88ca27";
    const char *ciphertext_hex = "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";

    unsigned char key[16]; // 128-bit key
    unsigned char iv[16];  // 128-bit IV
    size_t ciphertext_len = strlen(ciphertext_hex) / 2;
    unsigned char *ciphertext = (unsigned char *)malloc(ciphertext_len);

    // Convert hex strings to binary
    hex_to_bytes(hex_key, key, sizeof(key));
    hex_to_bytes(iv_hex, iv, sizeof(iv));
    hex_to_bytes(ciphertext_hex, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    // Allocate memory for the decrypted text
    unsigned char *decryptedtext = (unsigned char *)malloc(ciphertext_len);
    if (!decryptedtext) {
        handleErrors("Memory allocation failed");
    }

    // Decrypt the ciphertext
    int decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv, decryptedtext);

    printf("Decompressed text is:\n%s\n", decompressedtext);

    free(ciphertext);
    free(decryptedtext);

    return 0;
}

This program stops on EVP_DecryptFinal_ex, with the following error
40311ABD377B0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:107:
Error: Final
Aborted (core dumped)

I have tried loading unsigned chars directly without converting but I am getting the same effect.
Expected Results


Your key is hex decoded 16 bytes in size, i.e. AES-128 is applied, not AES-256, i.e. EVP_aes_128_cbc() must be used instead of EVP_aes_256_cbc() in the C code.

@Topaco yes, The issue was changung EVP_aes_256_cbc() to EVP_aes_128_cbc()
